# Count many items in one query

Tags: mysql, count

This is what I got at the moment:

```
SELECT `p`.`name`, SUM(`count`) FROM `player_items`
LEFT JOIN `players` `p` ON (`p`.`id` = `player_items`.`player_id`)
WHERE `itemtype` IN (2148, 2152, 2160) GROUP by `player_id`, `itemtype`
```

It withdraw player name and the `SUM` of the item types with ID 2148, 2152, 2160.

I need to rewrite this query so it will select items count for each ID, this is how the results should look like:

```
| NAME   | ITEM | COUNT |
| Player | 2148 | 10    |
| Player | 2152 | 760   |
| Player | 2160 | 0     |

|  NAME   | ITEM | COUNT |
| Player1 | 2148 | 890   |
| Player1 | 2152 | 5560  |
| Player1 | 2160 | 2584  |
```

Structure:

```
Table name = player_items
ITEM ID(2148, 2152, 2160) - itemtype
ITEM COUNT - count.
```

Keep in mind that each item id can have other "COUNT" value for example for one player in the player_items table will look like:

```
PLAYER_NAME | 2148 | 10
PLAYER_NAME | 2148 | 4
PLAYER_NAME | 2148 | 4
PLAYER_NAME | 2152 | 60
PLAYER_NAME | 2152 | 20
PLAYER_NAME | 2160 | 100
```

Let me know, if you don't get anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what your problem is. Don't you just want to return the item id (called itemtype) ??

```
SELECT 
    `p`.`name` AS `Name`,
    `i`.`itemtype` AS `Item`,
    SUM(`i`.`count`) AS `Count`
FROM
    `player_items` AS `i`
LEFT JOIN 
    `players` AS `p`
    ON
        (`p`.`id` = `i`.`player_id`)
WHERE 
    `i`.`itemtype` IN (2148, 2152, 2160) 
GROUP BY
    `i`.`player_id`,
    `i`.`itemtype`
```

This is a community wiki so it can be corrected if need be.

Comment: Also you probably want an inner join unless you have missing players